# Converting API response to mapped class object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm working on an angular project that has Firebase integrated. Once the data is fetched, I want the plain object to have some additional properties and maybe a few methods in the future. These new properties will be calculated based on the existing data and some business logic. Some of these properties are only UI-specific (I know I can create a pipe for such properties but if there are like 10 of them that needs to be transformed for presentation, should I be making 10 different pipes assuming that each one uses different logic?)

To represent the raw response, I've created a DTO using an interface and in order to have additional data, I made a separate class.

Moreover, the raw JSON response doesn't have the same format. Some properties are in the snake case while some are in the camel case. I want every property in my class to follow the camel case and when it's time to save the data back to the database, I want to convert my class back to the exact format as it was in the DTO (any additional properties and methods from must be removed during transformation.)

Let's take an example of `UserDataDto`. Assuming that it looks like this along with its corresponding class:

```
export enum AppLangCode {
  english = 'en_US',
  german = 'de_DE',
}

export interface UserDataDto {
    settings: Record<AppLangCode, string>;
    fullName: string;
    email: string;
    user_name: string;
    // Some more properties from the response
}

// Question: Should this implement "UserDto"? If I do, then I'm unable to rename or change the type of the property
export class UserData {
    userName: string; // in DTO, it was user_name
    email: string;
    fullName: string;
    settings: Map<AppLangCode, string>; // Changed the type here
}
```

I know I can always go with the manual mapping but isn't there any good library that would help me to go through all this? I've seen solutions that ask you to add a method like `toJSON` or `toDTO` on the class that would do manual transformation but this will make me rewrite the properties again which is quite annoying.

Now, a few questions here:

1. Am I over-complicating stuff or is this how it is supposed to be done?
2. I've tried the `class-transformer` library but I've some doubts like the last published date of this package was 2 years ago. As more years pass by, this could get worse if the project is updated to the latest version but the library isn't updated.
3. I want to avoid getters because binding with those in the HTML makes them trigger on every change detection cycle. Is it really the case?
4. Do you prefer immutable.js with this especially when playing with the classes and not plain objects?
5. If I have separate classes that are binding in the HTML of the components, should all these properties of the class be `public`?

I'm open to any suggestions and looking forward to hearing a better way of doing everything above in the best way.

Comment: What I typically do is have a apiInterface that can be mapped to, directly by the httpClient, then I have dedicated interfaces or classes for presentation and a pipe for converting one into the other. You don't need to make ten pipes for each property, you could just pipe the whole api interface into the presentation interface. Typically using 3rd party packages can get annoying when doing custom logic like that so I'd try and keep things simple as possible. And yeah sadly you need to have public properties for data binding if you are using classes

Comment: @Blye Thank you for the response. If I completely omit the classes, I would have to attach the new properties directly to the object. If at some point, I have to calculate them again, I would need a method that would be ultimately lying as a method of the service, or in component, or maybe under the utils whereas it should be a part of the actual class logic itself.

Comment: Question is when you have to calculate them again. Cause if it's only when you get new data you can comfortably store that logic in a pipe. Despite it being somewhat counterintuitive that's the whole point of pipes. I may be missing something here though.

Comment: I get your point but that doesn't sound like a neat option. A pipe is usually used to transform a single value to a more representable form not transforming the whole object.

Comment: At the end of the day pipes in angular are just a function that can be flagged as a pure function so that change detection doesn't rerun them if used in a template. Theres not much rules to where you apply them. I agree about it not being neat though. If you do come up with something better, ping me, it's always nice to see different implementations.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overcomplicate your code. The "interface" of data related to the dbs should be only "visible" in the service. The service return the property data and your components only take account the "UserData" interface

In your service, e.g.

```
getData(id:number)Observable<UserData>{
  return this.httpClient.get(...).pipe(
        map((x:any)=>{
            return {userName:..,email:...,fullName:...,settings:...}
        })
  )
}

getList()Observable<UserData[]>{
  return this.httpClient.get(...).pipe(
        map((res:any[])=>{
            return res.map(x=>{
               return {userName:..,email:...,fullName:...,settings:...}
            }
        })
  )
}

updateData(data:any){
      const value:UserData={....}
      this.httpClient.post(...,value)
}
```

The way as the data received by your service doesn't import to yours components (think that you can change the dbs in a future and you only want to change the service)

Comment: Should I use class for "UserData" and another interface to represent the raw response? Also, your example code above is creating UserData object at multiple places. The logic should be there one time only for creation.

Comment: If your "Class" has not method, not use class, simply Interfaces. Yes, you can use a "parse" "format" functions to pass from UserDto to UserData. Really Angular transpile to javaScript, so the use of Interfacte it's only to "help us" when codding. You can declare in the same service.ts the UserDto interface, but you neend't export

Comment: Okay, got it. Another thing, the UserData would extend the UserDto to have the additional properties but when saving the data, I have to exclude those extra properties and keep only the properties that are in the UserDto.
Is this how its supposed to be done?

So it will be two mappers in total. Also, the "parse" and "format" would require manual mapping or is there a good library that could do for me by using decorators or something.

Comment: I don't know any library, but It's possible exists. To eliminate a property of an object you can use [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) -generally it's not necesary but depends of your API. Take account to use a "optional" property, you can use the `?` or add as type `| undefined`. You can use spreadOperator to copy "simple object" (event you can use to remove unnecesaries properties (see e.g. this [link](https://dev.to/darksmile92/js-use-spread-to-exclude-properties-1km9)